# two qubits measurment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

Let

$$\text{qubit} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} (i∣00\rangle + ∣10\rangle − 2 ∣11\rangle) \, .$$

I need to calculate the probability for each state while measuring both qubits in the standard basis.
I did : for the 00 state : 1/6
for the 10: 1/6
for the 11: 4/6
That is ok? or i need to normalize the result? this is allready normalized?

"We measure the first qubit in the standard basis. What are the probabilities of getting |0> and |1>? Given that we measured |1 >, what is the
state after measurement."

The possabilitises for 0 on the first qubit is just 00 state and because of that its like the posability for 00 and in the last qustion we calc 1/6.
For the first qubit to be 1 lead us for 2 states 10 and 11 and therfor 4/6+1/6=5/6.
Am i right?

Afterwards "If we measure only the second qubit in the |+>; |-> basis, what
are the probabilities for the dierent results and what are the states after
measurement."

Now how i sopuose to do that? to calculate one in standard basis and the second on the +/- basis?
Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to normalize the result? this is allready normalized?

Do the frequencies add up to 100%?

> For the first qubit to be 1 lead us for 2 states 10 and 11 and therfor 4/6+1/6=5/6. Am i right?

You can answer this with the same technique as for any measurement. A measurement needs a bunch of orthogonal finals states. You need to orthogonally project your qubit onto a subspace where each of those orthogonal vectors is either completely in your space or completely orthogonal to the subspace.

Just identify orthogonal vectors in your subspace and the vectors orthogonal to it. If your qubit can be written as a linear combination of those vectors then the parts orthogonal to the subspace go away and you have your projection. The squared length of your projection is the frequency this happens when you do it many times from the start.

> Afterwards "If we measure only the second qubit in the |+>; |-> basis, what are the probabilities for the dierent results and what are the states after measurement."

Same thing, find an orthonormal set of final states that span your collection of possible final states. Then write your qubit as a part orthogonal to that and a part that is in that space. Find the part in the space, its squared length is the probability, and that vector is the actual result.

So you should be able to ask yourself if you have a basis for the final states and if you have enough and if they are orthogonal. You should be able to write your quibit as a sum of two vectors one that is a sum of those vectors and one that is orthogonal. Both of those can be checked and if so you are good. Throw away the part that is orthogonal, now you have your result. Compute the squared length that is your probability.

Its just about writing a basis for the measurement. You can write $0$ and $1$ in terms of $\pm$ so you can get it in that basis pretty quickly.